# How to avoid Method Not Allowed in IIS

Tags: iis, post, http-status-code-405

I have a utility I created for converting various types of media to other formats.  All works great locally on my IIS site, but when I move it to the Windows Server where it is to reside I get the a "405 Method Not Allowed" error when I attempt to send an XMLHttpRequest containing the file and some text to my php script for conversion.  It seem to be something about the POST method that is being block. I have added POST to the list of allowed access control methods on my IIS server but I am not sure what else has to be done to allow the POST method to be completed successfully.

Comment: When I look at my response header is see a line that says: "Allow GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE" Obviously this is an issue that POST isn't there.  Problem is I don't know where this is set.  I also see where I have set the access control methods "Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" but that seems to be overriden by the "Allow"

Comment: Well maybe it didn't have anything to do with that I manually added "POST" to my "Allow" header in my web.config file and that changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Well I feel very silly, but I answer my own question to hopefully save others from running into the same issue.  PHP was installed on my local web server but not in the production environment.  Very stupid of me not to think of this right away, but hopefully this answer will save some others a few hours of frustration.